# Complex grouping and ordering with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like

```
data = {
    'A': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'world', 'world', 'bar', 'foo'],
    'B': ['text1', 'text2', 'text1', 'text3', 'text2', 'text3', 'text1'],
    'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
}
```

It should be aggregated/grouped/indexed by A and B, and counted by C e.g. `df.pivot_table(index=['A', 'B'], values='C', aggfunc='count')`.

What I can't achieve is my desired order. The result should look like:

```
           C
A     B     
world text2  1
      text3  1
bar   text1  1
      text3  1
foo   text1  2
      text2  1
```

A has a fixed order (world > bar > foo) and B is ordered by descending counts in C.

Comment: how do you define the "fixed order"?

Comment: world before bar before foo .. so not alphabetically/numerical

Comment: So defined using a list, like `order = ['world', 'bar', 'foo']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), then reindex/slice with the desired order:

```
order = ['world', 'bar', 'foo']
out = df[['A', 'B']].value_counts().loc[order]
```

Output:

```
A      B    
world  text2    1
       text3    1
bar    text1    1
       text3    1
foo    text1    2
       text2    1
dtype: int64
```

Variant using [`groupby.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html):

```
out = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).count().loc[order]
```

Or if you really want to use `pivot_table`:

```
out = df.pivot_table(index=['A', 'B'], values='C', aggfunc='count').loc[order]
```

Output:

```
             C
A     B       
world text2  1
      text3  1
bar   text1  1
      text3  1
foo   text1  2
      text2  1
```

Other variant with an ordered [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
df['A'] = pd.Categorical(df['A'], categories=['world', 'bar', 'foo'])

out = df[['A', 'B']].value_counts().sort_index(level=0, kind='stable')
```

Comment: the first solution worked. 
the second was crushed by additional columns in the data (which wasn't part of the simple example) und the pivot_table one doesn't sorted C

Comment: @Nachtgold yes, I forgot to add a `sort_values(ascending=False)` in the intermediate examples ;)